# how to put new obj in ARToolKit for android

Tags: android, artoolkit

I need import my own Object, i tried in arsimplenativecars replace the cars but it didnt work.
I have changed the version in gradle but still did not work.

I need help plz.

Answer (score 0):

In the ARToolKit Forum there are several similar Questions about this topic. Go there and use the Search Field.

Beside of that probably you find your solution here? [ARToolKit](http://artoolkit.org/community/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=16052&p=20493&hilit=replace+obj+android#p20493)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the native part of the Projekt, in the Case of ArSimpleNativeCars the ARWrapperNativeCarExample.cpp, you have also to rebuild the native part. One solution would be to go in the JNI folder and run the ndk-build command.

> I have changed the version in gradle but still did not work.

The other thing is to increment the versionCode of the gradle file, so that changes of the assets Folder will be recon.